# How to get the status code of a website

Tags: http-status-code-405

I wanna get the status code of "www.google.com" by these codes:

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost method = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.i("LOG", "Code : " + code);

    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it gives me the code "405" means we have a problem.
what's the problem with this code?
give me another code to do the same job.but please a simple code. I'm a begginer :)

By the way 
I've heard httpclient is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe www.google.com let's you do a `POST`. That end-point likely only accepts `GET` requests.

Try googling for a website that accepts dumpy posts. Or standup a test website that accepts POSTs. That should be pretty easy using `node.js`.